# Xcode build in background and/or on save

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Is there a way to build my project in the background on save? Is this not recommended for any reason? I realize I can write a directory watching script which calls xcodebuild for my scheme, but I've yet to find anyone else doing it and wonder why.

This would be especially useful for projects with multiple frameworks where I could watch a framework folder and recompile that framework so it's ready when I go to build my entire app.

Comment: imo, the best way to do this is to setup Xcode server.

Comment: @johnelemans I've only used build bots on commit. Does Xcode server build on save and bring the the artifacts back to my local machine?